# how to auto "enter" in batch

Tags: batch-file, enter

I have a batch script to copy a file by dragging and dropping. When the file is dragged into the window the user is required to press "Enter" to continue. How can i bypass this? I have read a number of posts referring to vbscript, but I was hoping if this could be done with out it?
 My script is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set Dest="C:\My Doc"

set /p CS=Drag and Drop file:
Echo.

if exist !Dest! (
xcopy /y /q !CS! !Dest!
)

Explorer.exe !Dest!

EXIT
```

The script itself works perfectly, but I would like to bypass the requirement to press enter after dragging the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the window have to be open? This can easily be accomplished by dragging the file to copy onto the .bat file itself and setting CS to be equal to `%1`.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont wish to use VBScript? It's close to batch, and is a default included windows language. If the reason is anything other than a distaste, then it should be noted.

Comment: The Batch above is called by another batch, so is opened automatically within the window. i was not aware that vbscript was included in windows, i am still new to scripting i did a search in windows and could not locate it so assumed it was outside software.

Comment: @PBlank22 VBScript and JScript are interpreted by `cscript.exe` (or `wscript.exe` when you don't need the console), the same way .bat scripts are interpreted by `cmd.exe`.  They're all natively included in Windows without needing any downloads.  I'm not sure what Arescet hoped to learn from his question, but I think you can safely ignore it.  If he has a VBScript solution to offer, he should post it as an answer.  Asking you to learn a new language simply because he doesn't know how to solve your problem in batch is not reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think SomethingDark's comment offers the best solution.  If you must have drag-and-drop onto a running script, you can borrow from PowerShell's .NET console methods to watch for the end of the input without requiring the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```perl
@echo off
setlocal
Set Dest="C:\My Doc"

<NUL set /P "=Drag and drop file: "
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell "do {[void][console]::ReadKey().KeyChar} while ([console]::KeyAvailable)"'
) do set "CS=%%~I"

echo;

if exist "%Dest%" (
    xcopy /y /q "%CS%" "%Dest%"
)

explorer.exe "%Dest%"

exit /b
```

Comment: this just flashed "invalid number of parameters" and closed the window

Comment: @PBlank22 I get the same error when the destination folder doesn't exist.  Make sure you modify the third line as needed.  Otherwise, it works exactly as you've written it.  Other than my removing the need for delayed expansion (which can clobber file names containing exclamation marks), the only thing I changed was the method of reading the dragged-and-dropped file.  All the rest of the code is yours, for better or for worse.

Comment: not sure where the fault is, the destination is correct i have just checked but still have the same fault.

Comment: @PBlank22 remark out `@echo off` (like this: `rem @echo off`) and add a `pause` immediately above `exit /b`.  Can you tell which command is resulting in the error message?  You could also `echo You dropped "%CS%"` somewhere to make sure the filename contained in the `%CS%` variable is correct.